remote encryption nixos server not reachable
I'm trying to setup my server to start remotely. The problem is, it is not reachable, so I can't specify a Password to decrypt my drive.
I don't now what the problem is here wake on lan works. I also tried with static IPs as you can see from my config.
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  imports =
    [ # Include the results of the hardware scan.
      ./hardware-configuration.nix
    ];

  # Bootloader.
  boot.loader.grub.enable = true;
  boot.loader.grub.device = "/dev/sdc";
  boot.loader.grub.useOSProber = true;

  boot.initrd.luks.devices."luks-66286b25-900f-4ab7-b892-4a06be1c84c1".device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/66286b25-900f-4ab7-b892-4a06be1c84c1";
  # Setup keyfile
  boot.initrd.secrets = {
    "/boot/crypto_keyfile.bin" = null;
  };

  # SSH activation in initrd for decrypting drive over SSH
  boot.kernelParams = [ "ip=::::::dhcp" ];
  #boot.kernelParams = [ "ip=192.168.178.58::192.168.178.1:255.255.255.0:nixos:eth1:none" ];
  boot.initrd = {
    enable = true;
    availableKernelModules = [ "e1000e" ];
    systemd.users.root.shell = "/bin/cryptsetup-askpass";
    
    network = {
        enable = true;
        ssh = { 
            enable = true;
            port= 2222;
            authorizedKeys = [ "ssh-ed25519 <my-key> <user>@alpha" ];
            #authorizedKeys = config.users.users.root.openssh.authorizedKeys.keys;
            
            hostKeys = [ "/etc/secrets/initrd/ssh_host_rsa_key" ];
            };
        };  
    };

  boot.loader.grub.enableCryptodisk = true;

  boot.initrd.luks.devices."luks-74a8a33d-e694-4410-9e22-d839767d1bf2".keyFile = "/boot/crypto_keyfile.bin";
  boot.initrd.luks.devices."luks-66286b25-900f-4ab7-b892-4a06be1c84c1".keyFile = "/boot/crypto_keyfile.bin";

# Network configuration
  networking = {
    hostName = "nixos"; # Define your hostname.
    networkmanager.enable = true;
    useDHCP = false;
    defaultGateway = "192.168.178.1";
    nameservers = [
        "176.9.93.198"
        "176.9.1.117"
    ];
    interfaces.enp2s0 = {
        wakeOnLan.enable = true;
        useDHCP = true;
        ipv4.addresses = [{
            address ="192.168.178.58";
            prefixLength = 24;
        }];
    };
    firewall = {
        enable = false;
        allowedTCPPorts = [ 22 80 443 2222 ];
    };
};

  # Set your time zone.
  time.timeZone = "Europe/Berlin";

  # Select internationalisation properties.
  i18n.defaultLocale = "de_DE.UTF-8";

  i18n.extraLocaleSettings = {
    LC_ADDRESS = "de_DE.UTF-8";
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_DE.UTF-8";
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_DE.UTF-8";
    LC_MONETARY = "de_DE.UTF-8";
    LC_NAME = "de_DE.UTF-8";
    LC_NUMERIC = "de_DE.UTF-8";
    LC_PAPER = "de_DE.UTF-8";
    LC_TELEPHONE = "de_DE.UTF-8";
    LC_TIME = "de_DE.UTF-8";
  };

  # Configure keymap in X11
  services.xserver.xkb = {
    layout = "de";
    variant = "bone";
  };

  # Configure console keymap
  console.keyMap = "bone";

  # Define a user account. Don't forget to set a password with ‘passwd’.
  users.users.darks1de = {
    isNormalUser = true;
    description = "<user>";
    extraGroups = [ "networkmanager" "wheel" ];
    packages = with pkgs; [];
  };

  # Allow unfree packages
  nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true;

  # List packages installed in system profile. To search, run:
  # $ nix search wget
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    vim # Do not forget to add an editor to edit configuration.nix! The Nano editor is also installed by default.
    wget
  ];

  # Some programs need SUID wrappers, can be configured further or are
  # started in user sessions.
   programs.mtr.enable = true;
   programs.gnupg.agent = {
     enable = true;
     enableSSHSupport = true;
   };

  # List services that you want to enable:

  # Enable the OpenSSH daemon.
  services.openssh = {
    enable = true;
    ports = [ 22 ];
    settings = {
        PasswordAuthentication = true;
        AllowUsers = null;
        UseDns = true;
        X11Forwarding = false;
        PermitRootLogin = "yes";
    };
};

  system.stateVersion = "24.05"; # Did you read the comment?

}

journalctl -b | grep e1000e
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 00:19:99:bc:21:a1
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 10, PHY: 11, PBA No: 313130-031
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0: Disabling ASPM L0s L1
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0 0000:02:00.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0 eth1: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 00:19:99:b5:f6:0f
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0 eth1: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0 eth1: MAC: 3, PHY: 8, PBA No: 313130-033
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from eth1
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Aug 25 11:02:14 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Link is Down
Aug 25 11:02:26 nixos kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx

